# Problem with query to select distinct login

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select for each cod_user login that didn`t match to his login. Example: a -> acc (where in the table actually is abb).

I need it for some tests in data base in SoapUi.
I start with this, but can´t go any further for now:

```
SELECT U1.COD_USER, U2.LOGIN
FROM   USERS U1
       INNER JOIN USER U2
       ON U1.LOGIN != U2.LOGIN
```

table name users

```
+----------+-------+
| cod_user | login |
+----------+-------+
| a        | abb   | 
| b        | acc   | 
| c        | add   | 
| d        | ahh   | 
| e        | agg   | 
| f        | ann   | 
+----------+-------+
```

But that query gives me all logins for each users that he didnt use and i only need one. Thanks you.

Comment: can you explain what you are expecting to see? its not clear

Comment: I want to see a cod_user with any login that doesnt much his

Comment: @AlexDanilov that doesnt much his with what?

Comment: "Example: a -> acc" Where is that `a -> aac` relationship coming from because it is not in the sample data? Your query is joining the `USERS` table to the `USER` (without an "s") table; what is the structure of the `USER` table and what data does it contain or is that a typo? "but can´t go any further for now" Why not? Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] that contains enough information to demonstrate the full extent of your problem, the expected output and why your solution does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT U1.COD_USER,
       MAX(U1.LOGIN) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM) as UNUSED_LOGIN
FROM USERS U1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM USER U2
                  WHERE U1.COD_USER = U2.COD_USER AND
                        U1.LOGIN = U2.LOGIN
                 )
GROUP BY U1.COD_USER
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. 
I use sql developer and after this query it gives me ORA-00904:"U2.LOGIN" invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

In your both table, you must have a column which match. Like Cod_user must be common field and that needs to be used on join logic. So, just modify the your SQL like below

```
SELECT U1.COD_USER, U2.LOGIN
FROM USERS U1 INNER JOIN
     USER U2
     ON ( U1.COD_USER=U2.COD_USER and U1.LOGIN!= U2.LOGIN)
```

Comment: Thank you first of all, but it doesnt return any result.

Comment: Do you have Code_user field in USER table? if yes, then no result means there is no invalid login.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to assign to each user some random login belonging to other user from the same table and this assigned values should be distinct. So:

```
with t as (
    select cod_user, login, count(1) over () cnt,
           row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) rn
      from users )
select a.cod_user, a.login, b.login as random_login
  from t a 
  left join t b on a.rn = b.rn + 1 or (a.rn = 1 and b.rn = b.cnt)
  order by a.cod_user
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a9046cbbc4819be7c283afe5d9b94c7a)</sup>**

I assigned random row numbers to rows, then made self join on `a.rn = b.rn + 1`. First row must be joined exceptionally to the last, this is why `count() over ()` was used. Probably you could also use `mod()` for this.

Assignment is random (due to dbms_random used for ordering) and unique. If you run this query severeal times you will get different, random, unique values.